# Everything snapping to grid after some accident hotkey. Precise changes available only when I'm holding CTRL

Tags: snapping

My cat jumped on the keyboard, and now everything keeps snapping to grid.
For example, I create and grab new primitive, or extrude vertex, and if I'm not holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, it will not move until I move mouse cursor far away - then at some moment it will jump there, snapping to the grid cell.

So my question is - how to turn off this "snap mode"? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I've solved this.

Comment: "My cat jumped on the keyboard..." haha, classic! Anyway, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 2):

Mode: Edit or Object modes

Hotkey: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

Menu: Mesh/Object » Transform » Snap

Once the tool is activated you are ready to drag your element(s) to its(their) destination. Move your mouse pointer to the target where you want to snap to, hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, move your pointer to adjust (especially if your target is an edge or face).

When satisfied with the result, confirm with LMB Template-LMB.png or <kbd>Enter</kbd> (as usual, you can cancel everything with a RMB Template-RMB.png click or by hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd>).