# vertices don't move or extrude properly

Tags: vertices

i have this problem with my model as i was following a character modeling tutorial and suddenly my vertices are stuck on their positions.. and i do not remember what settings i changed(may be its because i once selected all pressed W and smooth), but now whenever i try to move/extrude a vertex it either doesn't move at all or moves only when i drag the mouse far away.. like in the picture. Please help.[image]

Comment: if your object is small it might be because you've enable the snapping and it makes the vertices stick to the grid?

Comment: I don't remember doing that but how can I un snap it??

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46305/everything-snapping-to-grid-after-some-accident-hotkey-precise-changes-availabl  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35235/how-to-turn-off-jumping-by-parts-when-moving-snapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to disable the *Snap* option, it might be because your vertices stick to the grid:

[image]

Comment: Oh alright thanks I will try that :)

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.. I don't know when did i do that. But its fixed now.. thanks again :)